# Cocoa Binding NSButton change the target for binding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionviewitem

I have a NSButton(provided delete item action) in the NSCollectionViewItem, the argument is set successfully the binding actions is responded and I also got the representedObject. But the target I m binding is the file's owner [image: image for target binding]

here is the method i got the representedObject:

```
- (void)removeAction:(id)object{
//    [_arrayController removeObject:object];
}
```

My problem is how to get the "`_arrayController`" instance or change the binding target to the `ViewController` that own the `arrayController` property?

Comment: BTW I m using Xcode 8.2.1, any comments will appreciated.

Comment: Dont use the binding and connect the action of the button to the first responder?

Comment: Which object is the file's owner?

Comment: @Willeke thanks man, first, I did create a delegate method to pass the button click events, but thing got weird the delegate(viewController managing NSCollectionView and own the arrayController property) value always nil when I click the button. Second, the file owner is NSCollectionViewItem instance.